# How to mock this to continue the async.each() call

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mongoose, promise

I have the following method, `removeOldObjects` that I want to unit-test. It removes objects from the list of existing objects. I believe the objects are mongoose instances. I understand what the method is doing, and I'm trying to mock the inputs to it, including the `remove()` method in `return existinObj.remove(cb)`. Doc for the real `remove()` is here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html (Model#remove([fn]) section). It looks like it's supposed to return a Promise.

I'm struggling to figure out how to effectively make `return existinObj.remove(cb)` do `return cb(null)` to move the `async.each()` call to its final callback, or even how the Promise is supposed to complete this method. I toyed around with using a Promise, but did not get anywhere (recently just picked up Javascript/Node)

How do I need to define `removeMethod` (in the script section below) so that I can test this method properly and reach the final callback?

Method:

```
const _ = require('underscore')
...
removeOldObjects (keepObjects, existingObjects, callback) {
  let objectsToReturn = []

  async.each(existingObjects, function (existinObj, cb) {
    let foundObj = _.find(keepObjects, function (thisObj) {
      return existinObj.id == thisObj.id
    })

    if (foundObj) {        
      objectsToReturn.push(object)
      return cb(null)
    } else {
      // Would like below to in effect behve like "return cb(null)",
      // so it can reach the final callback at the end
      return existinObj.remove(cb)
    }
  }, function (err) {
    return callback(err, objectsToReturn)
  })
}
```

Test script (using Mocha):

```
const test = new MyClass()
const keepObjects = [{id: 5}]  // removeDeadCams() does not hit its final callback
// const keepObjects = [{id: 1}]   // removeDeadCams() runs its full course
const existingObjects = [
  {id: 1, remove: removeMethod}
]
test.removeOldObjects(keepObjects, existingObjects, function (err, res) {
  console.log('error-----')
  console.log(err)
  console.log('response-----')
  console.log(res)  
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose document `remove` method returns a promise only then, when callback is not provided. In `removeOldObjects` implementation it's provided. So you shouldn't return a promise, instead of this you should call provided callback:

Add `remove` function to each `existingObjects` item and call callback from here:

```
const test = new MyClass()

const oldObjects = [
  { id: 5 }
];
const existingObjects = [
  { id: 1, remove: cb => cb(1) } // call it with id of the item to validate in your test
];

test.removeOldObjects(oldObjects, existingObjects, function(err, res) {
  console.log(res); // outputs [null, 1] 
})
```

Comment: Glad that and _it_ was helpful, going to answer all your questions about mocha:)